# PostGIS and geometry column

Tags: geometry, postgis-2.0

I have a csv table. Each record includes a start node (lat1,lon1) and an end node (lat2,lon2).
I have already imported the .csv into Postgresql 8.4. Now I would like set the geometry column. I tried to use this sql statement:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET the_geom = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || lat1 || ' ' || lon1 || ' ' ||
               lat2 || ' ' || lon2 || ')',4326);
```

but I receive this warning message:

```
WARNING:  OGC WKT expected, EWKT provided - use GeomFromEWKT() for this
            ERROR:  new row for relation "mytable" violates 
            check constraint "enforce_dims_the_geom"
```

Do you have any idea on how to add geometries in my case?

Answer (score 7):

You're constructing a POINT with four ordinates. To the parser that looks like a POINT ZM. You want to construct a LINESTRING.

```
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(lon1, lat1), ST_MakePoint(lon2, lat2)), 4326)
```

Comment: I run the query and I visualized the results in QGis. However each point is connected by a line. I tried to remove the ST_MakeLine but it doesn't work. Could you please tell which is sql statement that allows me to obtain points?

Comment: You have two points, surely they are meant to form a line? If you want them to be pointilist, just wrap them into a union, so you get back a multipoint.

Comment: ST_SetSRID(ST_Union(ST_MakePoint(lon1, lat1), ST_MakePoint(lon2, lat2)), 4326)